# Have Code which should save string from file in an Array, but did not giving output if I try to print the array

Tags: c, split

I am trying to learn C, and am writing a program which can

- open a text file
- split the string read from it
- save the result in an array, so I can work with it later.

I don't get any output from my code, however.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

FILE *fp = fopen("document.txt", "r");
char *string[255];
int i = 0;

char singleLine[255];
char *ptr;

while (fgets(singleLine, 255, fp) != NULL) {

    printf("The Line is: %s\n", singleLine);
    ptr = strtok(singleLine, ";");

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Splited: %s\n", ptr);
        strcpy(string[i],ptr);
        printf("Saved first Split Result: %s\n", string[i]);
        i = i + 1;

        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            strcpy(string[i],ptr);
            printf("Saved second Split Result: %s\n", string[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

//should print me all splited Strings  
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    printf(string[x]);
}
return 0;
}
```

My Textfile:

```
TCP/1;TTL/0

TCP/2;TTL/1

TCP/3;TTL/32
```

How can I fix my code so that it does the steps mentioned above?

Comment: No output? Really?

Comment: Just a note: you should always check if your file pointer is not NULL before using it.

Comment: Jup... i Dont know why, I work with Eclipse and build the C compiler into Eclipse. Everythink is still working but i dont get any output... :/

Comment: @Jesse u r right, i just forget it in my code.. for now :D.

Comment: @MustafaOtuzalti first thing to add: check `f != NULL` because it's probably the first issue. Then the program will crash, and applying the answer below will fix that too...

Comment: Have you debugged your code, using breakpoint? Does your app go into **while** command?

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code causes the compiler to output. "untitled.c:36:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]        printf(string[x]);"  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c"`

Comment: running the original posted code (except using the current source file name rather than 'document.txt'  resulted in: `The Line is: #include <stdio.h>

Splited: #include <stdio.h>

Segmentation fault (core dumped)`  so the posted code fails even with the simplest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this `char *string[255]` you have defined a array of pointer but that is not what is needed here. you should define it like array of string `char string[x][y]`. x and y depends of size needed to hold the strings.

Also there is a potential bug in your logic here. It will give wrong result it will repeat the second split item in your result array.

I have bit corrected it plz use this, though there are more optimization can be done in it:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("document.txt", "r");
if (!fp)
{
    perror( "failed to open file" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

char myString[100][255];
int i = 0;

char singleLine[255];
char *ptr;

while (fgets(singleLine, 255, fp) != NULL) {

    printf("The Line is: %s\n", singleLine);
    ptr = strtok(singleLine, ";");

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Splited: %s\n", ptr);
        strcpy(myString[i],ptr);
        printf("Saved Split Result: %s\n", myString[i]);
        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    printf("%s", myString[x]);
}
```

Comment: @MustafaOtuzalti you marked this as correct and voted up then removed the vote ? Is there any problem with the solution ?

Comment: ok fine, however it can further be improved. And upvotes motivates :)

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the operation failed.

Comment: Edited as per suggestion in last comment. Added (!=NULL) check

Answer (score 1):

`char *string[255]` is just an array of pointers. Change this to `char string[x][255]` where x is a number big enough to hold all rows.

Comment: Well, it did work when I tried it. And I get some output from your original code.

Comment: this fix or use `strdup` on the strings should work, unless the file cannot be opened. So double error

Comment: can it be, that i dont get a Output, because i use Eclipse?  I will trie it with VisualStudio and told u if every think work, but thanks for know :)

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. does not result in a seg fault event
4. is properly/consistently indented
5. properly checks for errors

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("untitled.c", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char *string[255];
    int i = 0;

    char singleLine[255];
    char *ptr;

    while (fgets(singleLine, 255, fp) ) 
    {
        printf("The Line is: %s\n", singleLine);
        ptr = strtok(singleLine, ";");

        //while (ptr != NULL) {
        while( i < 255 && ptr )
        {
            printf("Splited: %s\n", ptr);
            //strcpy(string[i],ptr);
            string[i] = strdup( ptr );
            printf("Saved first Split Result: %s\n", string[i]);
            //i = i + 1;
            i++;

            ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
            //if (ptr)   
            //{
            //   strcpy(string[i],ptr);
            //   printf("Saved second Split Result: %s\n", string[i]);
            //   i = i + 1;
            //}
        }
    }

    //should print me all splited Strings  
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) 
    {
        printf( "%s", string[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the first part of the output of the program.

```
The Line is: #include <stdio.h>

Splited: #include <stdio.h>

Saved first Split Result: #include <stdio.h>

The Line is: #include <stdlib.h>

Splited: #include <stdlib.h>

Saved first Split Result: #include <stdlib.h>

The Line is: #include <string.h>

Splited: #include <string.h>

Saved first Split Result: #include <string.h>

The Line is: 

Splited: 

Saved first Split Result: 

The Line is: int main(void) 

Splited: int main(void) 

Saved first Split Result: int main(void)
```

The following is the last part of the output from the program:

```
The Line is:    return 0;

Splited:    return 0
Saved first Split Result:   return 0
Splited: 

Saved first Split Result: 

The Line is: }

Splited: }

Saved first Split Result: }

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
```